# jquery to php post 500 internal server error with .load

Tags: php, jquery

I was googling for a few hours but I'm still stucked with this.
I'm trying to send data to a php file with .load jquery function.
I'm trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var commentCount = 2;
        $("button").click(function() {
            commentCount = commentCount + 2;
            console.log("Coment Count: " + commentCount);
            $("#comments").load("load-comments.php", {
                'commentNewCount': commentCount
            });
        });
    });
```

And my php should receive this variable as POST so I can get the information from a MySQL call.

```
$commentsNewCount = $_POST['commentNewCount'];
$more_comments->bindParam(':limits', $commentsNewCount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$more_comments->execute();
$more_all_comments = $more_comments->fetchAll();
foreach ($more_all_comments as $key => $rs) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo $rs['author'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $rs['message'];
    echo '</p>';
}
```

I checked the console from the developer tool and I get the following error:

```
POST http://my_url/load-comments.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I already try to implement a try catch in the .load function but I wasn't be able to get the error message, I printed several console.log as a mode for debugging but I don't know what could be the error.

This is for printing in real time, searched in google but can't find something like this, a lot of people use more complex functions like $.ajax or something like so I'm guessing my error is very simple.

Please, help me with your wisdom.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Also, try `var_dump` after each step. You might be missing a declaration of a variable or something similar.

Comment: The load() method loads data from a server and puts the returned data into the selected element.

Comment: this method is only for get dont for send data

Comment: use this for send data to php file: $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "Data Saved: ");
  });

Comment: Where is the `->prepare()` strange that you should leave out so much of the important code

Comment: @Tegito123 If a data object is provided, `.load()` uses POST, not GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data with load(), I think that the error is in the server side, you should check, debug or use var_dump in php and maybe you can use postman and send a post request with the param commentNewCount in the body. *ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/*

The load() method send a GET request if you only pass the url, but if you pass a params object it send a POST request, check https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3d732cca6b5076a9d13eee98e2b075b37384cd91/src/ajax/load.js#L34

For example:

```
$( '#comments' ).load( 'load-comments.php', 
  { commentNewCount: commentCount },
  function() {
    console.log('server return');
  }
);
```

Comment: How does this fix the problem on the server?

Comment: If you are sure that the problem is not in the front end you can check in the server side(some people said that you can't send data with load() ), the question doesn't have a lot of code form the backend, maybe the problem is with the db connection or anything else, but if you know how He can fix the problem on the server maybe you should add a comment and help @Barmar

Comment: 500 errors are practically always due to problems in the server script. Someone else already posted a comment, it's the first one, there's no point in me adding another one. I'm just not seeing how you expect this answer to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if your jQuery in anyway send a POST and not GET request to the PHP file, therefor try to do this first in your PHP file:

```
if(!$_POST['commentNewCount']){
  die("No post request sent");
}elseif(isset($_GET['commentNewCount'])){
  die('It was a GET request :)');
}
```

Comment: Even easier is to use `$_REQUEST['commentNewCount']`

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to all of you. With all your answers I manage to solve my problem, now I feel like I should tell what I did (most based in your answers) and conclude that my error was because a very simple thing.

In the end I did to versions of my front file (the one with the jQuery code). As you mention in some answers I check the server side, I tried to get the response of server with console.log and to achieve this I also hardcode my server side php file like this:

```
$commentsNewCount = $_POST['commentNewCount'];
$more_comments->bindParam(':limits', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$more_comments->execute();
```

And I get an error about I can't reference a parameter so I changed to this:

```
$more_comments->bindValue(':limits', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

That fixed the last error but now I had the problem with the 500 POST error, first I tried to print with console.log and what i get was an empty array [] so I run in console I run in console my php file. I found the error there! My variable $commentsNewCount had been taken as a string so in the end I just changed this line to this:

```
$more_comments->bindValue(':limits', intval($commentsNewCount), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

And wow! Now it's working.
Following advice I write two versions so I can learn, one was the one I proposed first and the other with .ajax; look:

The original:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery code!
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var commentCount = 2;
        $("button").click(function() {
            commentCount += 2;
            //console.log("Coment Count: " + commentCount);
            $("#comments").load("load-comments.php", {
                'commentNewCount': commentCount 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The one with .ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //jQuery code!
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var commentCount = 2;
        $("button").click(function() {
            commentCount += 2;
            $.ajax({                        
              type: "POST",                 
              url: "load-comments.php",   
              data:"commentNewCount=" + commentCount,
              success: function(data)            
              {
                console.log(data);
              }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you again for all your advice. And I hope my answer is well redacted as well.